# Failed to read session data after updating php 7.1 to 8.1

Tags: php, session, server, php-8.1

`Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data: user (path: /tmp)`

**`Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data: user (path: /tmp)`**

After lots of Googling and cursing found out The above error can be thrown on various reasons:
Folder permissions -> Given
Folder unavailability -> Folder there

But i have checked all above not these reasons. Iam using db sessions . Can anyone help me to solve this issue .

Comment: 2 thoughts. 1: It has to be a permission issue if the folder exists. Try creating a different folder and set it writable (writable by the user that the web server runs under). 2: Also... are you sure it is not because the browser is re-using an old session? Am not sure what happens if same session is used with newer PHP version. To test this, try clearing all cookies from the browser or use a browser profile that doesn't have any cookies set for your server.

Comment: _"Iam using db sessions"_ - not sure why it should try to read anything from the file system then in the first place. Can you elaborate a bit more, what exactly "db sessions" means in your case? Custom implementation, or ...?

Comment: DB sessions means sessions saved in data base table . https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php

Comment: @AVRajan no not those reasons already tried

Comment: Well... is the browser sending the cookies in the header or not? If not, then cookies are not set for the session. Are you using cookies for the session?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Solution i Have Got]

I have got the solution issue is due to when reading session it is returning null by adding this code solved. Thanks!

Comment: You should avoid posting screen shots like that. You can paste details in as text and link to more detailed documentation if needed.

Comment: Thank you this helped me to find out what was the issue.